# Android UpDate Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

With this code I update the value in the table. That value is stored in two tables. How can I do the update at the same time in the other table? Would also update the value in the other table just for that added in the last year .... is it possible?

This is my code for update table:

```java
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    ContentValues values1=new ContentValues();

    values.put(CategorieTable.NOME_CATEGORIA,fname );
    values1.put(GiornateTable.CATEGORIA,fname );////////////////


    System.out.println("");
    if(isUpdate)
    {    
        //update database with new data 
        dataBase.update(CategorieTable.TABLE_NAME, values, CategorieTable._ID+"="+id, null);
        dataBase.update(GiornateTable.TABLE_NAME, values1, GiornateTable._ID+"="+id, null);
    }
    else
    {
        //insert data into database
        dataBase.insert(CategorieTable.NOME_CATEGORIA, null, values);
        dataBase.insert(GiornateTable.CATEGORIA, null, values1);
    }
    //close database
    dataBase.close();
    finish();
```

Comment: the other table is NOME_CATEGORIA?

Comment: please be more specific as you don't state your problem quite clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
if(isUpdate)
{    
    //update database with new data 
    dataBase.update(CategorieTable.TABLE_NAME, values, CategorieTable._ID+"="+id, null);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int thisYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    if( yourDate == thisYear -1)
    dataBase.update(CategorieTable.OTHER_TABLE, values, CategorieTable._ID+"="+id, null);
}
```

just call the 2nd table. But it's too easy to be your answer

Comment: ok but how do I change the value of the second table only if inserted in the current year?

Comment: you mean the 2nd table needs to get the value of previous year?

Comment: with the code that you suggested can simultaneously edit the values ​​in Table 2.
But I would like the value of the second table is only changed when inserted in the current year. Ps. in the second table I have a field "DATE" in "TEXT".
Above you can see the modified code as per your suggestion.
I hope I've explained well.